# Export multiple emails to one csv file

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am trying to export all emails in specific folder "Not actioned DO" to a CSV file then move these emails to another folder "Actioned DO".

I edited code I found.

Only the last email is saved on the csv file.

I need all emails to be in the same CSV file.

```
Sub PseudoArchive()
Dim objNamespace As Outlook.NameSpace
Dim sourceFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim destinationFolder As Outlook.MAPIFolder
Dim Items As Outlook.Items
Dim Item As Object
Dim msg As String
Dim i As Long

Set objNamespace = GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set sourceFolder = objNamespace.Folders("msroumi@hotmail.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Not Actioned DO")
Set destinationFolder = objNamespace.Folders("msroumi@hotmail.com").Folders("Inbox").Folders("Actioned DO")
Set Items = sourceFolder.Items

'Move emails in sourceFolder to destinationFolder
msg = Items.Count & " Items in " & sourceFolder.Name & ", Move?"

If MsgBox(msg, vbYesNo) = vbYes Then
    For i = Items.Count To 1 Step -1
        Set Item = Items.Item(i)
        DoEvents
        Item.Move destinationFolder

        Item.SaveAs "D:\Excel\Learning Excel VBA\Outlook VBA\MyEmail.txt", olTXT
    Next
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Firstly, you are sving the item after it's already been moved (and deleted). Call SaveAs **before** calling Move. Or use the returned value of the Move function to reset the item: `set Item = Item.Move destinationFolder`.

Most importantly however, is that you are saving all message with the same file name, continuously overwriting the old files, thus only the last file survives. Make the file name unique - you can ether use the message `Subject` property for that (make sure you remove all invalid chars, such as `":"`) or you can do something as simple as adding a counter to te hfile name:

```
Item.SaveAs "D:\Excel\Learning Excel VBA\Outlook VBA\MyEmail" & i & ".txt", olTXT
```

Comment: thanks Dmitry for these information, i change the save ass option before the move, but how can i let all emails save in thee same file? because an excel file will import these emails from the CSV file, so can i let the outlook export all these emails to the same CSV file? thanks in advance

Comment: No, you cannot do that - Outlook only saves one file per message. It is your responsibility to merge these files or create the file explicitly in your code one line at a time without using SaveAs.